# Insert WooCommerce product id dynamically in shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**Set-up**

I have a WooCommerce store with Elementor.

I'm using an Elementor single product page template to generate the product page for each product.

I want to use [this plug-in](https://wordpress.org/plugins/premmerce-woocommerce-product-bundles/) to display a Frequently Bought Together (FBT) element on each product page.

To display the FBT element, the creator of the plug-in provides the following shortcode: `[premmerce_get_bundles_by_main_product_id id="X"]`, where `X` is a WooCommerce product id.

---

**Issue**

The `X` is not dynamic.

If I fill in the product id of e.g. product `2` in the shortcode, the Elementor product page template will display the FBT products of product `2` for each of my products.

---

**Question**

Can I make the `X` dynamic? Preferably, the `X` is set automatically to the product's id which page is being visited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to extend the shortcode:

```
function so_extend_frequent_bought_shortcode() {
    global $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();

    return do_shortcode( '[premmerce_get_bundles_by_main_product_id id="' . $id . '"]');
}
add_shortcode( 'my_new_shortcode', 'so_extend_frequent_bought_shortcode' );
```

Now you just need to put`[my_new_shortcode]` in your posts.
If you can't edit your functions.php, use a plugin called [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/)

Comment: Nice! But why did you not edit and extend my answer?

Comment: Oh *facepalms*. I rarely used SO to reply so I missed the edit part, sorry about that..

Answer (score 3):

You can only use dynamic data in shortcodes if you output the shortcode like this:

```
global $product;
$id = $product->get_id();

echo do_shortcode( '[premmerce_get_bundles_by_main_product_id id="' . $id . '"]');
```

see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/